# VueJS 3 passing data to a multiselect in a child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Im trying to pass data from my parent component to the child component's multiselect drop-downs. I have four but have only included one for example purposes.

If I duplicate the code from the parent to child to get 'uniquelocations', it works okay but I would prefer not to duplicate the code for obvious reasons. I need the code to be in the Parent for other functions.

I managed to get the function ' @on-reset="resetForm"' to work okay but I cant get this to pull in the data. Im new to this so probably missing something obvious.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Parent component**

```
 <Child       
        @on-reset="resetForm"
        :passUniqueLocations="returnUniqueLocations" />


 methods: {
    returnUniqueLocations() {
      return this.uniquelocations;
    },
```

**Child component**

```
<Multiselectlocation
                  @click="passUniqueLocations()"
                  :hide-selected="true"
                  role="combobox"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-label="combobox"
                  title="Select a location"
                  id="MultiLocation"
                  v-model="locations"
                  **:options="uniquelocations"**
                  :close-on-select="true"
                  mode="tags"
                  :searchable="true"
                  placeholder="Select a location(s)"
                  :track-by="trackBy"
                  @search-change="results"
                />


props: {
     passUniqueLocations: Function,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to pass all the parent's attributes to a child, use [Fallthrough Attributes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance) while [disabling attribute inheritance](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance).

If you want to pick and choose a few specific members of the parent's `this` and spread them onto a child, without having to bloat the `<Child />` tag by specifying each as a separate attribute, use a `computed` and `v-bind`:

```html
<script>
export default {
  props: ['p1', 'p2']
  data: () => ({
    d1: 'foo',
    d2: 'bar'
  }),
  methods() {
    m1() {
      console.log('m1 was called')
    },
    m2() {
      console.log('m2 was called')
    }
  },
  computed: {
    c1() {
      return 'foo'
    },
    c2() {
      return this.$store.state.c2
    },
    childAttributes() {

      // extract as many things as you want from `this`
      const { p1, p2, d1, d2, c1, c2, m1, m2 } = this

      // return them as an object
      return { p1, p2, d1, d2, c1, c2, m1, m2 }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <Child v-bind="childAttributes" />
</template>
```

If you have a really long list of members and you're bugged by the fact you need to specify each of them twice inside `childAttributes`, you might want to give `pick` a chance:

```js
import { pick } from 'lodash-es'

export default {
  //...
  computed: {
    childAttributes() {
      return pick(this, ["p1", "p2", "d1", "d2", "c1", "c2", "m1", "m2"]);
    },
  },
};
```

Motto: *all we are saaayiiing... / is give `pick` a chaaance...*

---

**Note**: my answer focuses on Options API because that's what you seem to be using. In Composition API you have multiple ways of doing the above but probably the most straight forward would be using a `reactive` object (+ `v-bind`, as above):

```js
const props = defineProps(/*...*/)
const childAttributes = reactive({
  ...props,
  // other refs or computed
})
```

Comment: Thank you @tao for your help. Its very much appreciated! I'm struggling to get this to work. Should all the methods and computed code be in the child component?

Comment: I can't answer that question without having a look at a *runnable* [mcve]. Consider [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) your local project into codesandbox and sharing the link.

Comment: In your example I mean. I can see this <template>  <Child v-bind="childAttributes" /></template> is in the Parent componenet but the other computed/methods etc, are these all in the Child component.

Comment: No, you *"collect"* them in the parent component and then, using `v-bind`, you can assign them all at once, so you don't have to specify them in the template one by one.

Comment: Thank you. I will do this. Your assistance is appreciated!